# Select dataframe rows matching date regular expression in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

In the following dataframe, how can I select rows that have date matching '2018-06%'?

```
Date                     Cost   Source
2018-06-01 00:00:77      0.03   RFP
2018-06-01 00:05:77      0.01   RFP
2018-06-01 04:09:77      0.90   EFO
2018-05-02 06:99:08      0.07   THP
2018-07-01 09:05:79      0.20   RFP
```

Expected output

```
Date                     Cost   Source
2018-06-01 00:00:77      0.03   RFP
2018-06-01 00:05:77      0.01   RFP
2018-06-01 04:09:77      0.90   EFO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have bad timestamps, which will make it difficult to convert to datetime and search by month.

My first recommendation would be to fix that data upstream, although if that is not an option, or if you are set on using regular expressions to match, you can simply use `^2018-06`:

```
df[df.Date.str.match(r'^2018-06')]

                  Date  Cost Source
0  2018-06-01 00:00:77  0.03    RFP
1  2018-06-01 00:05:77  0.01    RFP
2  2018-06-01 04:09:77  0.90    EFO
```

The regex is quite straightforward:

```
^           # Asserts beginning of string
2018-06     # matches your date
```

Comment: Thanks Chrisz, that worked!
Timestamp is not an issue, I wanted to select only current month data from the dataframe.

Comment: I am unable to convert your timestamps to datetime because of the hh:mm:ss are not valid.  If you have them as datetimes, there is a much easier way to solve this.